# Concept of "Rigidity" in mathematics. What is the idea?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, soft-question, galois-theory, intuition

I am reading from the book "Topics in Galois Theory" by Serre.

I came across the word "Rigidity". I am not able to understand this concept.

If I am not wrong, This term was first used by Thompson, He used this concept("Rigidity Method") to show that monster group can be realized as the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I don't have any intuition for this concept. I tried reading from the Wikipedia page on "Rigidity", but I got more confused. It says

> The above statement does not define a mathematical property. Instead, it describes in what sense the adjective rigid is typically used in mathematics, by mathematicians.

What is the idea ? One more question, What does the adjective "rigid" means in context of Galois theory.

---

Comment: I don't understand what Serre means here. I assume that the method you're talking about is the classic method of showing that a lot of simple groups are Galois groups over $\mathbb{Q}$ by understanding what the etale fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}-\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is (for $x_i$ rational). I don't know why he calls this 'rigid'. Rigidity is usually referencing when a category has 'less morphisms' than a larger category. For example, every complex manifold is a smooth manifold, but the former notion is more rigid than the latter since every holomorphic map is smooth but not

Comment: conversely. Similarly, varieties are more rigid than complex manifolds (unless both things are projective, say).